# How to know user has clicked “X” in other form?

Tags: c#, forms

I want to know if the user closed the secondary form, that be opened while running, to return the main form to be active.

Comment: Assuming WinForms: you could hook into the `Form_Closed` event. Or you could use `.ShowDialog()`

Comment: Please clarify if you're using WinForms or another UI technology.

Comment: Form_Closed event Irrelevant in other form.

Comment: _"Form_Closed event Irrelevant in other form"_ - explain, please. There's nothing to stop you from doing `form2.FormClosed += (obj, evnt) => MessageBox.Show("Form 2 was closed!");`. I don't see how it's irrelevant at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `FormClosed` event.

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed;
        this.Hide();
        form.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 closed");
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```